# Trying to install rpm file in termux

Tags: java, termux

I was trying to install java jdk 18.0.1 in termux and I have its rpm executable file but the problem is that termux does not support rpm . I also searched for its .deb file but main problem is this that there is no build for aarch64 processor from oracle. I also tried to install an alien package to convert the rpm file to deb but the same error hitted me which is. E: Unable to locate package alien

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to install a .rpm file to Termux. The only way is using qemu or proot